# PHP export to excel file size is geting too much bigger than actual file size

Tags: php, excel, excel-2007, export-to-excel

I am exporting some data to excel by PHP. which merely around 17k records. All the MySQL queries are returning results in less than 4 mins of time. and I have not used any complex looping for the excel generation just as follows :

```
<? php foreach($this->records as $type=>$record) 
   { 
?>
    <table>
        <tr><td><b>
             <?
               php ($type == 'installation')? $type1 = 'ABCD':$type1= 'EFGH';  
               echo strtoupper($type1); 
             ?>
        </b></td></tr>
    </table>
         <table>
              <?php foreach ($record as $k=>$newrecords) { 
              ?><tr>
             <?php 
             foreach($newrecords as $id=>$var1) { 
        ?><td <?php echo $class10; ?>> <?php echo " ".$var1.""; ?> </td>
             <?php 
            } echo "</tr>";
         } ?>
    </table>    
     <?php  
        }   ?>
```

File is taking too much of time to export and when gets generated it comes of 47.6 MB and take too much time to open. And when I open the file and save it without doing any change file size reduces to mere 400KB

If anyone knows anything about this issue please reply....

THANKS in advance.

Amit

Comment: why not you use csv file format for tabular data export. Its light weight can open as excel as well.

Comment: This is as per client requirement and he wants to do some more calculations and add more data manually after the excel generation.

Comment: what code you are using to generate excel file. As well check your sql query timeoput.